# Android convert CID location to Coordinates

Tags: android, google-api

I built an android app which can handle a share intent from Google Maps and show it's coordinates.

The problem is that they send a short url which I decode with Google's url shortner api and in some cases, the result long link is of this type: http://maps.google.com/?cid=3635533832900933072&hl=en&gl=us.

Can anyone help me on how to get the coresponding coordinates to *"cid=3635533832900933072"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest Google Maps update, the share intent contains the address name in the body which can be decoded with Geocoder into coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is no public API to get the location from a cid.

However, a possible workaround would be to parse the Google Maps output to obtain the latitude and longitude (though it may be brittle, if they change the result format).

*(Although the url contains `output=json`, it's not actually json -- that's why I parse it with `substring()` and such instead of using `JSONObject`).*

Try this code:

```
public static LatLng getCidCoordinates(String cid)
{
    final String URL_FORMAT = "http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=%s&q=a&output=json"; 
    final String LATLNG_BEFORE = "viewport:{center:{";
    final String LATLNG_AFTER = "}";
    final String LATLNG_SEPARATOR = ",";
    final String LAT_PREFIX = "lat:";
    final String LNG_PREFIX = "lng:";

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(String.format(URL_FORMAT, cid));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

        String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        int startIndex = text.indexOf(LATLNG_BEFORE);
        if (startIndex == -1)
            return null;

        startIndex += LATLNG_BEFORE.length();
        int endIndex = text.indexOf(LATLNG_AFTER, startIndex);

        // Should be "lat:<number>,lng:<number>"
        String[] parts = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex).split(LATLNG_SEPARATOR);
        if (parts.length != 2)
            return null;

        if (parts[0].startsWith(LAT_PREFIX))
            parts[0] = parts[0].substring(LAT_PREFIX.length());
        else
            return null;

        if (parts[1].startsWith(LNG_PREFIX))
            parts[1] = parts[1].substring(LNG_PREFIX.length());
        else
            return null;

        return new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]), Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Richard Yes, why? Is it broken?

Comment: @matiash Well, when I try to search details about a public transportation stop, JSON returns empty. :[

Comment: It seems that http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=%s&q=a&output=json is not working any more. Any other ideas on how to get the coordinates from cid?

Answer (score 4):

After reading this post yesterday, I found a new method to do it. I hope Google do not close this new API and hidden parameter. :)

You can use this API hidden parameter to get the coordinater. Usage: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=YOUR_CID&key=YOUR_KEY

It returns a result contains formatted address, place_id, name of the address and GPS coordinater.

Please see my blog to see more detail: https://leonbbs.blogspot.com/2018/03/google-map-cid-to-placeid-or-get.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Send request to the link
2. Retrieve response and parse body
3. Extract meta-info with the Place name
4. Place name can be used to find location by Geocoder

For example:

- there is a link: https://maps.google.com/?cid=13226830714359798441
- response body contains meta:

```
<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom" itemprop="name">
<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom" property="og:title">
<meta content="Big Ben · London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom" property="og:site_name">
```

Obtain Place location by Google Maps CID gist:

https://gist.github.com/asilichenko/b0000eb1562c9e4e75b0d43d799260bc